# Opening a Team in SharePoints opens Root Site when team is created by Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

when following the description in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/teams-create-group-and-team), at first glance everything seems to be alright. But when I click on the button "Open in SharePoint" in the General team channel, the root site collection is opened (https://tenant.sharepoint.com/) instead of the proper team site (https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/team).

Our tenant is in the targeted release.

Best regards
Phil

Comment: When you say Button, I hope you are trying to say Link on Teams >> General >> Files >> "Open in SharePoint". Sometimes it takes some time to create SharePoint site after new Team's creation. I am guessing in your case you are trying to access the SharePoint site even before it is created and that is the reason you are getting redirected to root site. Can you please test it one more time and let me know.

Comment: Actually I mean Teams >> General >> Three Dots in the upper right (More Options?) >> Open in SharePoint. Opening the tab 'files' shows the files and the click on 'Open in SharePoint' works fine afterwards. As I created the group before adding the team, the SharePoint site exists and works fine when I open it by URL in a web browser.

Comment: This seems to be no Graph API problem. Because the behaviour is the same when creating a group with a team from the Microsoft 365 admin center.